# Can the visual bell be enabled in Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, shell, cygwin

Trying to enable the visual bell for the Cygwin shell. I am running Cygwin 1.5. I don't have speakers, and would like a visual way to be notified of command line errors.

So far I have tried adding the following to my ~/.bash_profile

```
set bell-style visible
```

Comment: That's a setting of your terminal, not the shell, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual bell you defined is from Bash. If Bash don't find a way to display the visual bell, it fallback to audible bell. This is the case by default with Cygwin because the terminal is just cmd.exe (without any provision for visual bell).

You can modify the source code, but this is not very easy.
Or just use another terminal. For example puttycyg: http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/